# why file name "server.py" cannot be debugged in pycharm

Tags: debugging, flask, pycharm

It is very strange that file name called `server.py` cannot be debugged in pycharm, when i rename to other filename, the debugging breakpoint work in `server.py`. Why??

Comment: What do you mean *can not be debugged* ? Does the `server.py` run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known regression in 2019.2: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37124.

Should be fixed in 2019.2.2. Preview build is already available https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355